# BCC email receiving Purge notifications

Tags: docusignapi

We are receiving an email with the subject "Documents to be removed" to the BCC email address. These emails are related to the envelope purge.  Why are these sent to the BCC email box?, my understanding is BCC email box will only receive the same email's that were sent out from the account.

Answer (score 1):

Blind carbon copy allows you to add BCC recipients for an account. All envelope-related, system-generated emails for that account will be blind carbon copied to the verified addresses that are setup for the account. In your case, Purge Notification needs to go to sender account, since your email is configured as BCC email address so you are getting same Purge Envelope related notifications as well. If you do not want to receive it, then you can close your email address from your DS Account.